# Convert improperly formatted string into dictionary?

Tags: python

The problem right now is that I have a string

```
'{ecl:gry, hcl:#888785, eyr:2023, cid:63, iyr:2019, hgt:177cm, pid:656793259}'
```

I wouldn't be able to ast.literal_eval convert this to a dict because it isn't properly formatted.
So I tried wrapping alphanumeric characters with quotations.

```
        output = ""
        quoting = False
        for char in string:
            if char.isalnum():
                if not quoting:
                    output += '"'
                    quoting = True
            elif quoting:
                output += '"'
                quoting = False 
            output += char
```

However, some of the key, value pairs have values with special character beginnings.
Which has caused:

```
"hcl":#"888785",
```

Instead of:

```
"hcl":"#888785",
```

So the closest I've been able to get in reformatting my string for ast.literal_eval() is

```
{"ecl":"gry", "hcl":#"888785", "eyr":"2023", "cid":"63", "iyr":"2019", "hgt":"177cm", "pid":"656793259"}
```

How can I be inclusive of special characters while still converting this string into a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a oneliner that will do it.
This strips off the `{` and `}` characters, splits on `', '` then further splits each result on `:`. Those results then become `k`ey `v`alue pairs creating a dictionary.

```
sval= '{ecl:gry, hcl:#888785, eyr:2023, cid:63, iyr:2019, hgt:177cm, pid:656793259}'
sval = {k:v for (k,v) in [s.split(':') for s in sval.strip('{}').split(', ')]}
>>> sval
{'ecl': 'gry', 'hcl': '#888785', 'eyr': '2023', 'cid': '63', 'iyr': '2019', 'hgt': '177cm', 'pid': '656793259'}
```

Comment: Haha you recognized it right away! Thank you and this was so helpful! :)

Comment: Ingrained  from 5-1/2 hours ago :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `split` and `strip` inside of a generator expression to make this work in one line:

```
s = "{ecl:gry, hcl:#888785, eyr:2023, cid:63, iyr:2019, hgt:177cm, pid:656793259}"
d = dict(e.split(":") for e in s.strip("{},").split())
```

Comment: Code doesn't work. change `string.strip` to `s.strip`

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn didn't realize I changed it after I tested it the last time, thanks for catching.

Comment: I like that. I don't always remember that I can use `dict()` vs. `{}`